# Repeating ID's in console jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having one list box and when I click on one item from this list box to fetch the id of that value,  it is shown 5 times. I think that somewhere, it is returning again and again ... Please have a look. I don't know from where this error is coming but it returns 5 times as undefined

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "avb.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
         console.log("obj--",obj)
            var jsObject = obj;
            var usedNames = [];
            $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled',
                location: 'fixed'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1')
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {
                    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                    usedNames.push(value.name);
                }


               $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
    $('#listbox').toggle(this.value != "");
});

                $('#dropdown1').change(function() {

                    $('#listbox').empty();

                    $('<option>', {
                        text: 'Select your List Option',
                        value: '',
                        selected: 'selected',
                        disabled: 'disabled'
                    }).appendTo('#listbox');

                    var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                    console.log("as".selection);
                    $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                        if (value['name'] == selection) {
                            var optionHtml = '';
                            for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                                var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                                optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '">' + value[attr] + '</option>';



                            }


                            $("#listbox").css("width","500px")

                            $("#listbox").css("height","300px")
                            $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);


                            // $(this).data(val)

                            return false;
                        }
                        var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
                         console.log(selectedOption);

                    });

                });
                $("#listbox").on("click",function(){

                          console.log("asd",$('#listbox').attr('data-val'));
                          })
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In $.each you add a change handler to #dropdown1. It will add N handlers, depending on how many items are in obj.

Comment: add the change handlers outside the each function. Use each to add options to the select, but only set the change handler once, because it is per select, not per option.

Comment: Yeah it worked I moved change handlers after each functions